# Firing "play" for all videos in a function when parent is active in Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm building a Bootstrap Carousel with an mp4 video in each item. It looks like this:

```
<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="2000">
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
        <video width="100%" loop autoplay muted preload="auto">
          <source src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/slides/vid1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video> 
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <video width="100%" loop autoplay muted preload="auto">
          <source src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/slides/vid2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to trigger the play in each video once the parent element **.item** gets the **.next** class, which is applied when the preceding element finishes the transition.

Basically I'm trying to avoid the video playing in loop when the slide is in view.

From the Bootstrap documentation I see this:

> Bootstrap's carousel class exposes two events for hooking into
>   carousel functionality.
>
> Both events have the following additional properties:
>
> direction: The direction in which the carousel is sliding (either
>   "left" or "right"). relatedTarget: The DOM element that is being slid
>   into place as the active item.
>
> slide.bs.carousel This event fires immediately when the slide instance
>   method is invoked. slid.bs.carousel   This event is fired when the
>   carousel has completed its slide transition.

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
   // do something…
})
```

Could I just trigger play on  using this function or it would be easier to use a conditional based on the parent having the .next class?

Comment: Don't autoplay videos, period. Everybody hates that. It's intrusive, some people have their sound off, and it wastes bandwidth. Now, you're going to reply: "I have a good reason in this case...", but you don't. Trust me. There are no good reasons. Just leave the videos alone, only play them when the user clicks one, and set your carousel to pause-on-hover.

Comment: They are short videos in a loop with no sound, like an slider but with short videos, only for design purposes.